# Google Sheets IMPORTRANGE function: How can I find what documents are connected to my source?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I searched Google and specifically Stack Overflow for this information but was unable to find an answer.  I apologize if I missed it due to using the wrong search terms or some other silly reason.

I have connected many tracking documents to a primary source 'directory' document using vlookup/query combined with importrange to pull contact information, relevant leadership, etc.  We are overhauling these connections to be based on unchanging employee/location codes as opposed to by name as it's done currently.  My back-burnered ToDo to maintain a list of connected documents has now come to bite me.

Is there an efficient way to find what documents are connected to my source?  Something like a list of all other documents using importrange to 'look' at my source document.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's possible

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski should be possible to iterate over every sheet using Drive API, check every cell for `IMPORTRANGE` and make a list of used sheets this way... But would be nice to have a simpler solution. :)

Comment: @kishkin Remember that your sheet might be connected to someonelses' sheet. So you would have to go through not only your drive.

Comment: So basically you have a bunch of spreadsheets with `importrange` that has to be changed, right?

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski that is a nice addition! :) You might be able to go through the sheet directly as long as it was shared publicly. If permission for import was given manually (in ref error tool tip) than it would be cumbersome...

Comment: @Martí Yes, I have a number of tracking documents that need to show the current leadership or contact information.  Rather than manually updating many documents when changes occur, they are using importrange to pull the most current information from the master directory.

Comment: @kishkin Would that be something like a Google Apps Script function to loop through documents checking cells for the use of importrange?  In principle, I get it, but I think that may not be practical.  My employer uses Google Sheets extensively, and being in an upper admin position I have access to most things.  The sheer volume of documents/cells to check would be immense.  I think it may simply be time to build my tracking I should have had all along, update as much as I can, make the fix, and then see who cries about broken documents.

Answer (score 2):

To be completly honest, you seem to need a database. That being said you can programatically all the URLs used in `IMPORTRANGE` like so:

```js
function findImportUrls() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('URL of a sheet')
  const result = new Set();

  for (let sheet of ss.getSheets()) {
    // Find any cell with importrange in their formula
    const ranges = sheet.createTextFinder("importrange")
      .matchFormulaText(true)
      .matchCase(false)
      .findAll()
    
    // Go to each cell and extract URLs with regex
    for (let range of ranges) {
      getRangeImportUrls(range, result)
    }
  }

  // Print allthe URLs to console
  for (let url of result.values()) {
    console.log(url)
  }
}

function getRangeImportUrls(range, resultSet) {
  const formula = range.getFormula()
  if (!formula) return

  // Use regular expressions to extract any importrange url
  const regex = /importrange\("(.+?)"/gmi
  let m
  while ((m = regex.exec(formula)) !== null) {
      // Get the first group and add it to the result set
      resultSet.add(m[1])
  }
}
```

This uses the spreadsheet search functionality to find any formula with `IMPORTRANGE`. Then we use regex to extract the value from the formula. The finder may add ranges that contain the word `importrange` but they are not formulas. On those cases, the regex won't find anything and thus will be ignored.

The regex itself simply matches any text that is `importrange(` followed by text in double quotes. It saves the text inside the quotes as a group (to be extracted).

Note that this only gets the URLs from a single spreadsheet.

### References

- [Sheet.createTextFinder(findText) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [Regular expressions (MDN guide)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)